# largest integer in a number

Tags: c++

I would like to make a program which allows you to enter a number (say 145).  It reads the 3 integers and prints the largest one.

```
int a, b, c, max;

cout << "Enter a, b and c: ";
cin >> a >> b >> c;

max = a;
if (b>max)
    max = b;
if (c>max)
    max = c;
cout << "Max is " << max << "\n";
```

I was think of using something like this, but I have no idea how to get the computer to read each individual integer. Also, I am new to programming so I'd like to keep it simple to understand.

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you clarify your question?  What do you mean by "get the computer to read each individual integer?"  The code you have above will indeed read three integers from the user.

Comment: So, you want a number entered like "145" and not like "1[enter]4[enter]5[enter]"?

Comment: simple solution is to replace `int` with `char`

Comment: it would be great if you specify what is the input, what do you expect as the output and the actual output

Comment: Yes I just realized I can use the char to work I am just not sure how! I want comp. to read 145 and print the largest of those three..but as a single number not separate!

Answer (score 2):

The way you're reading in the numbers (`cin >> a >> b >> c`) requires them to be separated with whitespaces.

So if the intention is that each digit of `145` is interpreted as a number on its own, simply separate them with spaces when entering, like so: `1 4 5`.

If they *have* to be entered together, read them into `char` variables and then convert to numbers (by subtracting `'0'`).

Comment: @john: `ch - '0'` where `ch` is a char variable containing a decimal digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant digits instead of numbers, then you could use variables of type `char` and then convert them to integers (although generally this would not be needed just to see which one is greater). Alternatively, you could read a single number (which seems to be what you want), and get each of the digits by succesively calling `% 10, /= 10`.

Comment: Something in the lines of `int digit_a = char_a - '0'`.

Comment: but how would i separate each individual digit? that is where I am totally lost

Comment: If you read chars, then you are reading each digit in its char form. If you read an integer, you separate it into digits by using % 10 and /= 10, there has to be lots of examples out there on how to split a number into its base10 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
char a, b, c, max;
```

instead of

```
int a, b, c, max;
```

and you will get what you want.
Everything else leave unchanged

```
int main()
{

    char a, b, c, max;

    cout << "Enter a, b and c: ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    max = a;
    if (b>max)
        max = b;
    if (c>max)
        max = c;
    cout << "Max is " << max << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: That doesnt work because I want the program to real 145 and just that one char..then print that 5 is the largest number..using the logic that I used for comparing 3 separate numbers..145 enter and it says 5 is largest

Comment: I enter 145 and it says that 5 is the largest. What do you expect to be the largest?

Comment: yes but it is being entered separately..I want to enter as a single 144 or 124 and the program would say which digit is the biggest..input 145 then press enter and you get the answer

Comment: here is the copy of my console screen: `Enter a, b and c: 132
Max is 3 ` Is that is what you want to see?

Comment: but its being entered separately! I want input as a single [enter]

Comment: Are you sure you use my code (the one with `char a, b, c, max;`, not `int`? If so, rebuild the code and try again. When I enter 132 (without spaces) it shows 3. The code DOES work. Maybe it is just not compiled and you use the old one. Try to rebuild the project (delete the genereated .exe file first if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution:

```
int number;
int max = 0;

cout << "Enter a number : ";
cin >> number;

while (number != 0)
{
    if ((number % 10) > max) //Remainder of number / 10
    {
        max = number % 10;
    }
    number /= 10;  //remove the last digit
}

cout << "The largest number was " << max;
```